# How to facilitate secure chats between users

Tags: encryption, authentication, key-management, encoding

My company runs a chat room service where the users can securely send messages to one another. All users are authenticated by the service in advance, and will install software from the service onto their computer. The problem is, none of them want to go to the trouble of using public/private key pairs in order to distribute symmetric keys.

how could my company facilitate secure chats between users, without going through the hassle of using public/private key pairs in order to distribute symmetric keys?

Comment: Are you looking for end-to-end encryption, meaning even the server can't read content, or simply encrypted user to server? Most chat servers, such as Openfire, support the latter transparently to the users and the users can use a myriad of clients to interface with the standardized XMPP protocol.

Comment: Why would they need to use key pairs? You say the users can securely send messsages, and then your question is how can the company facilitate secure chats; what is the difference? Why do you think the current solution is not secure? What does "secure" mean, here, exactly?

Comment: another method of security without the hassle of using public/private key pairs in order to distribute symmetric keys

Comment: Why doesn't this "secure" chat app generate the key pairs automatically? Why is the end user involved?

Comment: this has nothing to do with the question as stated thanks for your sarcastic input